# Django + Angular 2 hash authentication

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make Django + Angular 2. Django as backend, angular as frontend. I already made authentication using rest api and JWT.

**PROBLEM**

When I do authentication I must send body (username/password), so I want to to secure this thing, for example using hash. 
My idea is to post username and password (from input field), but hash password (to secure), then decrypt it (mby even in django side) to make properly authentication in api.

Main problem is to secure password while do authentication, because now it shows in url.

Would be great to get any suggestions or ideas what could help me.

**EDITED**

I just edited all text, because I already found answers on some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do this.

You should already be using HTTPS for all communication between client and server. If this is the case, there is no way the data can be intercepted, so there is no need to hash the password for transport.

Just send it in the POST data, and use Django's normal authentication.